# Connection between the spectra of a family of matrices and a modelization of particles' scattering?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, mathematical-physics, cauchy-matrices

In the excellent book "Numerical Computing with MATLAB" by Cleve B. Moler (SIAM 2004), [Moler is the "father" of Matlab], one finds, on pages 298-299, the following graphical representation (fig. 10.12 ; I have reconstructed it with minor changes ; Matlab program below) with the following explanations (personal adaptation of the text):

Let $n$ be a fixed integer $>1$. Let $t\in (0,1)$ ; let $A_t$ be the $n \times n$ matrix with entries

> $$A_{t,i,j}=\dfrac{1}{i-j+t}$$

Consider Fig. 1, gathering the spectra of matrices $A_t$, for $n=11$ and $0.1 \leq t \leq 0.9$ with steps $\Delta t=0.005$.

[image]

*Figure 1. Interpretation : the 11 rightmost points correspond to the spectrum of matrix $A_t$ for $t=0.1$.*

There is a striking similarity with particles' scattering by a nucleus situated at the origin, with hyperbolic trajectories ; see for example [this reference](https://pirelli.hosted.uark.edu/testing/Unit5/CMwBang10Unit5.htm).

My question is :

> How matrices $A_t$ can be connected to a model of particle scattering ?

My attempts (mostly unsuccessful) :

- Consider $A_t$ as a Cauchy matrix ($x_i=i$, $y_j=j-t$) (notations of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix)  with its different properties, in particular displacement equation. See as well the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3512521).
- Connect $A_t$ with a quadratic form defined by its moment's matrix $\int_C z^{i}\bar{z}^{j}z^{t-1}dz$, $z^{t-1}$ playing the rôle of a weight function. But for which curve $C$ ?
- Prove that the eigenvalues are situated on hyperbolas.
- Make many simulations (see figures below).

Matlab program for Fig. 1 :

```
 n=11;
 [I,J]=meshgrid(1:n,1:n);
 E=[];
 for t=0.1:0.005:0.9
   A=1./(I-J+t);
   E=[E,eig(A)];
 end;
 plot(E,'.k');axis equal
```

Addendum (November 22, 2018) : Here is a second figure that provides a "bigger" view, with $n=20$ and $0.005 \leq t \leq 0.995$. The eigenvalues corresponding

- to $t=0.005$ are grouped into the rightmost big red blob on the right,
- to $t=0.995$ are blue filled dots (quasi-circle with radius $\approx 110$).

[image]

*Figure 2 : [enlarged version of Fig. 1 ; case $n=15$] Everything happens as if a **planar** wave enters at $t=0$ from the right, is slowed down by  nucleus' repulsion, then scattered as a **circular** wave...*

[image]

*Fig. 3 : Two cases are gathered here, both for $t=0.995$ : $n=51$ (empty circles) and $n=100$ (stars). One can note that the eigenvalues are very close to the $(n+1)$-th roots of unity. For this value of $t$, the  radii  are given by experimental formula : $R_n=200(1-12.4/n+212/n^2-3110/n^3)$.*

I am grateful to @AmbretteOrrisey who did very interesting remarks, in particular by giving the following polar representation for the trajectory of particles : [citation follows ; more details can be found in his/her answer]
"The polar equation of the trajectory of a particle being deflected by a point charge is

$$r=\frac{2a^2}{\sqrt{b^2+4a^2}\sin\theta -b}\tag{1}$$

where $a$ is the *impact parameter* which is the closest approach to the nucleus *were the path undeviated*; $b$ is the closest approach of a *head-on (* $a=0$*)* particle *with* repulsion operating."

Figure 4 displays a reconstruction result that takes into account the fact that (n+1)th roots of unity give asymptotic directions.

[image]

*Figure 4 : Case $n=201$. An approximate reconstruction of $21$ among the $n$ trajectories (Matlab program below ; polar equation - adapted from (1) can be seen on line 5). Please note the "ad hoc" coefficient $3.0592$...*

```
 n=201;
 for k=1:20:n
    d=pi*k/(2*(n+1));c=cos(d);
    t=-d+0.01:0.01:d-0.01;
    r=3.0592*(1-c)*exp(i*(t-d))./(cos(t)-c); 
    plot(r);plot(conj(r));
 end;
```

Slightly related : http://bdpi.usp.br/bitstream/handle/BDPI/35181/wos2012-3198.pdf

I mention here a book gathering publications of Steve Moler [Milestones in Matrix Computation] (https://global.oup.com/academic/product/milestones-in-matrix-computation-9780199206810?cc=fr&lang=en&) and an article mentionning the analycity of the obtain curves : (https://www.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/504/eigenv.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

I'm don't think the curves *would* be hyoerbolæ *anyway* if it were a model for classical scattering.

The polar equation of the particle being deflected by a point charge is

$$r=\frac{2a^2}{\sqrt{b^2+4a^2}\sin\theta -b}$$

where $a$ is the *impact parameter* which is the closest approach to the nucleus *were the path undeviated*; $b$ is the closest approach of a *head-on (* $a=0$*)* particle *with* repulsion operating, and $\theta$ is the angle between the radius vector of the particle (nucleus at origin) and the line joining the nucleus to point of closest approach *with* charge in place (***not***  the  axis of approach - ie the line through the nucleus that particle is moving parallel to & distance $a$ from when it is yet infinite distance away).

Is that a polar coördinate representation of a hyperbola? I suppose it ought to be, as it is an *inverse-square* force!

Anyway - it's likely I'll look into it will-I-nill-I, now.

Oh ... the *diæræsis* in "coördinate" & the *ligature* in "diæræsis" ... I'm hoping you don't mind that archaïck stuff too much - I *love* it ... but many would probably *go ballistic* if I used that kind of idiom more generally on here. They even complain about my *italics & **emphasis***! The diæræsis over the second vowel in a conjunction of vowels was a device used to denote that the conjunction *does not* form a diphthong. It *never was* actually a *very* widely-used convention!

Comment: Thanks a lot for these very interesting facts about scattering. I am going to have a closer look at it.

Comment: And possibly there's a storm of protest brewing at my linguistic devices already ... I keep forgetting that on this forum a post is _y-bumpen_ when it is answered!

Comment: As I'm not native english speaker and writer (I'm french), some words or expressions you use are unknown to me, like _y-bumpen_. Nevertheless, I appreciate precise/clear/high level/(and sometimes sophisticated) language ...

Comment: Made a slight error - fixed it ... I'm trying to recall it _on-the-fly_. I'll leave it now, so that I'm not _repeatedly_ bumping this post.

Comment: This _was_ originally meant to be a private conversation between me & someone who _specifically_ asked me to look at a post that was _unanswered_ for __2½ years__!! I just forgot that a post is _bumped_ (or _y-bumpen_) when it is answered. I'm _not atall_ bothered that it _isn't_ private afterall ... I'm just explaining why I relaxed a bit in my use of my preferred vernacular.

Comment: No! that's it! θ is the angle the radiusvector of the particle makes with a line at _a right angle_ to the line joining the nucleus (origin) to the point of closest approach, ie the _direction of motion of the particle_ at it's point of closest aporoach. Coz the distance of closest aporoach is (b+√(b^2+4a^2))/2. That's why it's better really changing it to formulation in terms of _cosine_; but the integral in Gradsteyn & Ryzhik is in terms of _sine_. It's coming back now. Comments don't _bump_ posts ... do they!?

Comment: No they don't, fortunately. Yes of course it's a hyperbola - I rembember now from celestial mechanics - a planet's orbit is 1/(1+ε.cosθ) with ε the eccentricity of the orbit (& scaled appropriately of course). So where were we - you wanted to prove that the curves in your graph are hyperbolæ, but couldn't. Please don't rely on my being able to do so - you've seen just now what kind of _gaps_ & _lapses_ I can be afflicted with. But I'll have a look ... and I _shall_, too, as this has indeed caught  my interest ... you never know - I might get an inspiration!

Comment: Couple of questions: do the curves go off to ∞ in their respective directions as t tends to the limits of its range; and as t tends to 0 is it -π to +π that the imaginary parts extend over? ... kind of _looks_ like it.

Comment: I think it's quite likely they are an abalogue of scattering, TBPH. Even this _wave_ interpretation that's used for calculating the scattering by a point with a _Yukawa_ potential: what you've shown here is reminiscent of that. You have y

Comment: to use the wave method with a Yukawa potential: if you try to do it classically you get an integral that's intractable - I've 'farmed it out' on here and the consensus seems to be that it _is_ intractable. So all it needs, then is for the 'trajectories of the solutions in rhe complex plane to be hyperbolæ with focus all at the same point. That's not really a _great deal_ to ask ... & I have a hunch they are that. So maybe scattdring _could_ be gorm

Comment: formulated in terms of these matrices. That's a fascinating area in it's own right: formulation of problems according to different _paradigms_. You have the _eigenfunction_ formulation of quantum mechanics, & the _matrix_ formulation. And I've seen - and mentioned in one of my previous posts on _Physics_ - a formulation of planetary motion in terms of _quaternions_ instead of vectors! _That_ was _thoroughly_ ingenious, to my mind.

Comment: I've just realised: the guy who protested at my lunguistic peculiarities was _you_! I didn't look at the name - I thought it was someone else! Anyway ... you know ... I do have a _passionate_ love of old English! I find it _so so_ temting to give it a _run out_!

Comment: And if anyone objects, I say to them "honi soix qui mal y pense"! (The motto of the Knights of the Garter.) I'll try to restrain this tendency, though. I hope I haven't given you too much difficulty so far.

Comment: "the guy who protested at my lunguistic peculiarities was you!" : when was that ? I don't remember ...

Comment: It wasn't so much _protested_: it's up there in the comments - 5hr ago now. You just mentioned that my use of certain archaic phrasings can be difficult. And I know perfectly well it can. It's perfectly fair to mention it.

Comment: In fact you didn't even _protest_ atall, really. But people sometimes do ... so when I see even a mere _mention_ of it I have a sort of _reflex_ that it's a protest!

Comment: I see how you found it impossible to prove that the curves are hyperbolæ though ... quite frankly I've never gone anywhere near deeply enough into the theory of solutions of polynomial equations of high degree (and the limit as degree increases without limit) to really know how to start with it. Maybe you could do it from the theory of _matrices_ & _eigenvalues of matrices __immediatelty___ - 'short-circuiting' the theory of polynomials & their solutions. ... & I feel thats how it _ought to be_ possible to do it.

Comment: Here's a question though: as _n_ increases, do the trajectories of the _outermost_ eigenvalues of the spectrum tend to _straight -lines_. I do feel _that_ ought to happen if these trajectories _are indeed_ analogues of particles scattered at a point-charge. I feel that some of the _width __supplied___ by increase of _n_ would 'go into' increasing the _density_ of trajectories, and the other some of it into _range_ of impact parameter - perhaps √n into each.

Comment: Something has _bumped_ (_y-bumpen_!) this ... but I can't find any new answer or modifcation of the question.

Comment: See "Addendum 2" I have done to my text.

Comment: Ah yes ... it didn't show-up the first time I saw it - this _app_ has weird behaviour in that way!

Comment: I probably caught it _just momentarily after_ you'd finished appending it ... so that the 'app' had updated its position in the list, but not the _content_. 20 min sounds about right for that to be so.

Comment: I have appreciated very much all your comments. A big big thank.

Comment: I can't make headway with proving that the cyr

Comment: curves are _hyperbolæ_; but I think they probably _are_: & I love this idea of a single algebraic _structure_ that _encodes_ all possible trajectories in the limit as its _n_ → ∞ rather than just a _single_ trajectory.