# How can I evaluate the following involving dirac delta functions?

Tags: signal-processing, dirac-delta

\begin{align}
\delta(x)\delta(x) = ? 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\delta(x)\delta(x-a) = ? 
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\delta(x)/x = ? 
\end{align}

In the above problems, a is a real number and a $\ne$ 0,  My solutions are below, but I am not sure of them.

\begin{align}
\delta(x)\delta(x) = \delta(x=0) \delta(x)=\delta(x)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
\delta(x)\delta(x-a) = \delta(x=a) \delta(x-a)=0 
\end{align}

since the $\delta$(x=a)=0

\begin{align}
\delta(x)/x = ? 
\end{align}
I am not sure of this.

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: About $\delta(x)/x$, see my answer to this recent question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3214395 and the first reference therein.

Comment: If $a=0$, would your answer to the second one be true?

Comment: @JeanMarie thanks for that, but is the derivative of $\delta$ defined ?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 thanks for pointing that out what is your opinion of when a not equal to 0. When a=0 , I believe the answer should be just $\delta$(x) ^2.

Comment: $\delta(x)^2$ is not defined.

Comment: @Adi The derivative of $\delta$ is a well defined concept (unlike its square) ; besides, physically, it modelizes a doublet (2 infinitely close opposite charges +q,-q) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_doublet

Comment: The function $\delta(x)^2$ may not be defined in a strict mathematical sense, but since you tagged this with 'signal-processing', I'd say that $\delta(x)^2=\delta(x)$ would probably be fine with your professor. Take my advice at your own risk though.