# How to derive this matrix identity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, positive-semidefinite, lyapunov-functions

Let $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ be distinct positive real numbers.
Define the $n\times n$ matrix $H$, where $H_{ij} = \frac{2}{x_i + x_j}$. Prove that:

$$
\mathbf{1}^\top H^{-1} \mathbf{1} = x_1+\dots+x_n
$$

where $\mathbf{1}$ is the $n\times 1$ vector of all 1's.

I can show that $H\succeq 0$ (positive semidefinite) and $H\succ 0$ when the $x_i$ are distinct, but I'm not sure how to proceed further. For a reference, see [Proving a symmetric Cauchy matrix is positive semidefinite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3512521/proving-a-symmetric-cauchy-matrix-is-positive-semidefinite).

Edit: I think this should be true even when the $x_i$ are not necessarily positive? (so long as $x_i+x_j \neq 0$ for all $i,j$).

Comment: There is a closed form for the [inverse of a Cauchy matrix](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Cauchy_Matrix).

Comment: @JimmyK4542 thanks for getting me on the right track. Looks like there is a proof posted here: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Elements_in_Inverse_of_Cauchy_Matrix